Alternating series of Laplace transforms is zero implies that Laplace transform is zero?
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
Suppose $\on{F}\left(s\right)$ is the Laplace transform of $\on{f}\left(x\right)$, and
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k - 1} \on{F}\left(rk\right) = 0,\quad r > 0
$$
Does it imply that $\on{F}\left(rk\right) = 0$, $\forall\ k$ ?.
What I know is that Laplace transform is unique.

Are you assuming the sum to vanish for all $r>0$, or just for a specific $r>0$?

For all $r>0$..

In which context did you find this?

Yes, if that summation is exactly zero for all $r$, then we shall have $F=0$ being the zero function. To prove this, it helps to consider the alternating summation as another sort of transform between functions. Namely, for any function $F$, let the alternating transform $A[F]$ be a new function defined as follows.
$$A[F](r):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}F(rk)$$
Then in essence, what you're assuming is that $A[\mathcal{L}[f]]=0$ is the zero function, and you're trying to prove that $f=0$. It's clear that $A$ is linear, in the sense that $A[F+c\cdot G]=A[F]+c\cdot A[G]$ for any suitable functions $F,G$ and scalar $c$, and in particular $A[0]=0$. Therefore, proving the implication $A[F]=0 \implies F=0$ is equivalent to proving that $A$ is injective. We can prove this easily at least when $F$ decays quickly in the limit of $r\to\infty$, and a little more work extends the result to most conventional cases.
I shall present an explicit inverse for $A$, although it requires some knowledge of the Dirichlet convolution. For convenience, let $\alpha_k = (-1)^{k-1}$ denote the alternating sequence, and let $\beta_k = (-1)^{k-1}\mu(k)$ where $\mu$ is the moebius function. It just so happens that $\beta$ is the dirichlet inverse of $\alpha$, so that $\beta*\alpha=\varepsilon$ is the Dirichlet convolution identity. The convolution identity is a trivial sequence, where $\varepsilon_1=1$ and $\varepsilon_k=0$ for all $k>1$. So long as $F$ decays quickly enough, we might perform the following rearrangements.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n\cdot A[F](rn) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_n\alpha_k F(rnk) \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty \sum_{n|d}\beta_n\alpha_{d/n}F(rd) \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty F(rd)\sum_{n|d}\beta_n\alpha_{d/n} \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty F(rd) (\beta*\alpha)_d \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty F(rd) \varepsilon_d \\
&= F(r)
\end{align}$$
In the above, the notation $\beta*\alpha$ refers to the Dirichlet convolution, which resolves to $\varepsilon$ as previously discussed. Since $\varepsilon$ is a very trivial sequence, we easily resolve the summation to be $F(r)$ exactly. Since we have recovered $F$ entirely from $A[F]$, we are safe to conclude that $A$ is injective. Consequently, whenever we have $A[F]=0$, then we shall also have $F=0$.

The above analysis requires that $F(r)\to 0$ quickly in the limit of $r\to \infty$, and the rearrangements may not hold in certain cases. You haven't given any restrictions on your function $f$, so it's difficult to analyze these subtleties. In our special case that $F=\mathcal{L}[f]$, our requirements should hold so long as $f(0)=0$, and $f$ is differentiable at zero, and the growth of $f$ is bounded by an exponential. In such cases, our rearrangements work because $\mathcal{L}[f](s)$ is bounded by $\mathcal{O}\left(s^{-2}\right)$. To prove absolute convergence, we use the fact that the divisor function $\sigma_0(d) = \sum_{n|d}1$ is bounded by $\mathcal{o}(d^\delta)$ for any constant $\delta>0$. By selecting $\delta<1$, we prove absolute convergence like so.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\beta_n\alpha_k F(rnk)| &= \sum_{d=1}^\infty |F(rd)|\sum_{n|d} |\beta_n \alpha_{d/n}| \\
&\leq \sum_{d=1}^\infty |F(rd)|\sum_{n|d} 1 \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty |F(rd)| \sigma_0(d) \\
&\leq \sum_{d=1}^\infty \mathcal{O}(d^{-2+\delta}) <\infty
\end{align}$$
For cases where $f(0)\neq 0$ but the other requirements hold, we can let $y_0=f(0)$ and $g=f-y_0$ and $G=\mathcal{L}[g]$, then we see $F(s)=G(s)+\frac{y_0}{s}$. We easily prove $A[\frac{1}{s}](r) = \frac{\ln(2)}{r}$, hence $A[F](r) = A[G](r) + \frac{y_0\ln(2)}{r}$. Since $g(0)=0$, then $G$ decays quickly enough to be recoverable. More specifically, $G(s)$ decays at least as fast as $\mathcal{O}(s^{-2})$, which should guarantee that likewise $A[G](r)$ is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(r^{-2})$, and this allows us to recover $y_0$ from $A[F]$ like so.
$$\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\lim_{r\to\infty} r\cdot A[F](r) = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\lim_{r\to\infty} \left(r\cdot A[G](r) + y_0\ln(2)\right) = y_0$$
After recovering $y_0$, we recover $A[G](r)=A[F](r)-\frac{y_0\ln(2)}{r}$, then $G=A^{-1}[A[G]]$, and finally $F=G+\frac{y_0}{s}$. Since $F$ is recoverable from $A[F]$, this proves $A$ is injective so long as the input takes the form $F=\mathcal{L}[f]$ where $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and doesn't grow super-exponentially.
